# Find paramater $c$ for parameterized p.d.f.

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the continuous random variable $X$ with p.d.f. $f$ given by

$$ f(x) = \frac{c}{(1+x)^{v+1}}$$

where $x \geq 0, v > 0$.

Find constant $c$ for which it is a probability distribution.

Idea:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx =  [ -\frac{c (x+1)^{v+1}}{v} ]_0^{\infty} = 1.$$

$F(0) = - \frac c v$ and what is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x) $? I am a bit confused about the second parameter $v$. I assume it must be irrelevant for the finding of $c$.

Comment: I believe you want to find c in terms of v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx = - \frac{c}{v(1+x)^v}\biggr\rvert^\infty_0=\frac{c}{v}=1\Rightarrow c=v$$